# Область видимости дочерних классов Python

Tags: python, архитектура

пишу простой TCP сервер, решил остановиться на такой архитектуре, напишу очень упрощенно чтобы была понятна суть ошибки.

```
class Server:
    connections = {}
    ...
    class Connection:
        ...
       def func(self):
           connections[self.key] = value
```

Внутри функции func доступа к connections нет, как и во всем внутреннем классе. В связи с этим два вопроса:

1. Где можно найти хорошее пояснение про области видимости вложенных классов
2. Как лучше организовать код основываясь на следующих идеях:

   - Есть класс оболочка (сервер)
   - Есть класс содержания (соединения)
   - У всех объектов содержания есть простой доступ к атрибутам объекта оболочки (self.parent.foo) очевидно, но громоздко
   - Оболочка легко взаимодействует с содержащимися объектами
     Надеюсь на ваше понимание

Comment: `connections` не является переменной. Его нет ни в `globals()`, ни в `locals()`. Это атрибут класса `Server`. Просто укажите это и у вас нигде не будет проблем с доступом к нему: `Server.connections[self.key] = value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предположить, что вам нужно что-то вроде этого

```
class Connection:
    pass

class Server:
    def __init__(server, *server_args):
        server.connections = set()

        class Connection_(Connection):
            server_ = server

            def __init__(client, *client_args):
                server.connections.add(client)
                # Отсюда видим
                # Экземпляр сервера:  server
                # Аргументы сервера:  server_args
                # Экземпляр клиента:  client
                # Аргументы клиента:  client_args
                # Соединения сервера: server.connections

        server.connection = Connection_

server1 = Server('server1_arg1', 'server1_arg2')
client1 = server1.connection('client1_arg1', 'client1_arg2')

server2 = Server('server2_arg1', 'server2_arg2')
client2 = server2.connection('client2_arg1', 'client2_arg2')

print(server1.connections)
print(server2.connections)
print(isinstance(client1, Connection))
print(isinstance(client1, server1.connection))
print(not isinstance(client1, server2.connection))
print(server1.connection.server_ is server1)
```

```
{<__main__.Server.__init__.<locals>.Connection_ object at 0x7f017db2eeb0>}
{<__main__.Server.__init__.<locals>.Connection_ object at 0x7f017db2ed60>}
True
True
True
True
```

Иначе нет особого смысла помещать один класс в другой.

Comment: А зачем объявлять пустой класс и наследоваться от него?

Comment: @ClickName Не обязательно пустой, он может содержать методы и поля, которые будет переопределены во внутренних классах. Смысл в том, что все соединения всех серверов будут связаны иерархией, даже не будучи экземплярами одного класса.